# Why the animationend would be triggered in another srcElement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events, animate.css

I make a function to handle css3 animate:

```js
function play( $elm, animateClasss ) {
    $elm.addClass( animateClasss ).one(
        'webkitAnimationEnd animationend',
        function( evt ) {
            if ( evt.target === $elm.get(0) ) {
                // here is the right target elment
            }
            else {
                // here, the evt.target sometimes will be another elment which is like:
                // '<div class="anotherAnimateClasss"></div>'
                // .anotherAnimateClasss not use the `play` function
            }
        }
    );
}
```

For example, when I use `play($('#a'), 'fadeIn')` and handle another element '' by use `$('.b').addClass('fadeOut')`, these two ways could make the `$('#a')` trigger chaos, sometime triggers `fadeIn`, sometime triggers `fadeOut`.

Last, what I want to known is that: I `addEvent` on `$elm`, but why the callback sometimes triggered in another element?

Comment: because event bubbles. Is that your issue?